# Nested View within Multiple views using ui router angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multiple views on one page and within one view I have nested view.How should I configure this in app.js.Given below is my code which is not working.
This is my index.html file

```
<body ng-app="configuratorApp" >
    <div ui-view="view1"></div>
    <div  ui-view="view2"></div>
</body>
```

This is my view1.html file

```
<div ui-view> </div>
<button  type="button" ui-sref="view1.child1"></button>
<button  type="button" ui-sref="view1.child2"></button>
```

This is my view1-child1.html file

```
<h1>Child1<h1>
```

This is my view1-child2.html file

```
<h1>Child2<h1>
```

This is my view2.html file

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

This is my app.js file

```
.state('home',{
    url: '/',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'index.html'
        },
        'view1@home': {
            templateUrl: 'view1.html' 
        },'view2@home': {
            templateUrl: 'view2.html' 
        }
      }
})
.state('view1.child1', {
        url: '/child1',
        templateUrl: 'view1-child1.html'
    })
.state('view1.child2', {
        url: '/child2',
        templateUrl: 'view1-child2.html'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You confused the views with the states.

There is no `view1.child1` state, reason being you do not have a `view1` as a parent state (unless the code you posted above is incomplete). The name should be `home.child` instead.

```
.state('home.child1', { //this should be home.child1 instead of view1.child1
  url: '/child1',
  templateUrl: 'view1-child1.html'
})
.state('home.child2', {
  url: '/child2',
  templateUrl: 'view1-child2.html'
})
```

Also bear in mind that you will need a root template (or unnamed root template) in your `index.html`, else your `home`state cannot be populated.

So in your index.html, you need to have this:

```
<body ng-app="configuratorApp">
   <div ui-view></div> <!--this is the root template, to let Home state 'live' here-->
</body>
```

Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5NZ3tbeh7V6E8U6Pmel?p=preview)

*P.s. if the plnkr is not working just refresh it. sometimes it has problem fetching the htmls*